# Rails missing template in own gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, missing-template

I forked a gem and changed some things, but I am really desperate. I always get Template is missing:

> Template is missing
>   Missing template spree/addresses/index, spree/store/index, spree/base/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:de, :en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :haml, :rabl], :versions=>[:v1]}. Searched in: * "/Users/Manu/Documents/rails_projects/my_store_dev/app/views" * "/Users/Manu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/spree_my_favourites-6076d6ee5cb2/app/views" * "/Users/Manu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/spree_address_book-b66e2abf6429/app/views" * "/Users/Manu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/spree-promotion-roles-rule-0fd33e96c5c4/app/views" * "/Users/Manu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/spree-promotion-exclude-specials-rule-1debc9765387/app/views" * "/Users/Manu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/spree_better_terms_and_conditions-8001a85040eb/app/views" * "/Users/Manu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spree_quick_cart-2.2.3/app/views" * "/Users/Manu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/spree_i18n-1d94e07c68c7/app/views" * "/Users/Manu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/spree_auth_devise-01901766a256/lib/views/backend" * "/Users/Manu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/spree_auth_devise-01901766a256/lib/views/frontend" * "/Users/Manu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.4/app/views" * "/Users/Manu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/spree_gateway-5cbe3890d1a0/app/views" * "/Users/Manu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/spree-33c8fa4d51d8/frontend/app/views" * "/Users/Manu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/spree-33c8fa4d51d8/backend/app/views" * "/Users/Manu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/spree-33c8fa4d51d8/api/app/views" * "/Users/Manu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/spree-33c8fa4d51d8/core/app/views" * "/Users/Manu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/kaminari-0.15.1/app/views"

This is my routes file:

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.draw do
  # Add your extension routes here
  namespace :account do
    resources :orders, only: [:index]
    resources :favourites, only: [:index]
    resources :addresses, only: [:index]
  end

end
```

This is my `AddressesController` in `controller/spree/account/`:

```
module Spree
  module Account
    class AddressesController < Spree::StoreController

  before_filter :check_logged_in_user

  def index
    @user = try_spree_current_user

  end

  private

  def check_logged_in_user
    unless try_spree_current_user
      account_addresses__path 
      redirect_to spree_login_path 
    end
  end

  end
 end
end
```

I have a `index.haml` in `views/spree/account/addresses/`, and this is part of rake routes:

```
account_orders GET    /account/orders(.:format)                                     spree/account/orders#index
account_favourites GET    /account/favourites(.:format)                                               spree/account/favourites#index
account_addresses GET    /account/addresses(.:format)                                                spree/account/addresses#index
```

Can someone please give me a hint?

Answer (score 3):

I had an similar experience, not sure if this applies to you or not but here it is:

This is the error I got:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate at / . 
Missing partial spree/shared/_google_analytics with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder, :rabl], :versions=>[:v1]}. Searched in:
* "/Users/sjones/work/cs-spree/app/views"...
```

But it turns out the partial actually exists and is even being parsed and run (I use the RubyMine debugger to check)

The error is incorrect. In my case a helper method `try_spree_current_user` was missing from the controller, and this missing method `NoMethodError` error was somehow being trapped and replaced with the `MissingTemplate` error shown.

Fixing that error caused the template to load just fine.

Like I said, this may not be your problem, but this is so weird I'm posting this for others.

Comment: +1 because it's totally true, i got it after installing spree_theme and was related with using `Spree::Tracker` which was not defined anywhere

Comment: If anyone has same error - just add https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_analytics_trackers and it should work then.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error after installing extension [spree_theme](https://github.com/vinsol-spree-contrib/spree_themes)

`Missing partial spree/shared/_google_analytics`

i ended up finding the file (so it was not missing at all) here: `public/vinsol_spree_themes/current/views/spree/shared/_google_analytics.js.erb`

after debugging a bit finally detected a missing class of `class not defined` type error with something `Spree::Tracker` so all i had to was to fix that dependency and the thing worked, **as mentioned above** by [stujo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2993768/stujo) sometimes it seems this message is not related with the file itself but with external causes

this is how i'm generating my project from scratch if you proceed this way you will probably dont have any more issues and will be able to run spree `3.5` just fine

**Spree base installation from scratch**

** Assuming you have an empty rails app **

***Update Gemfile***

`gem 'spree', '~> 3.5.0'`

`gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.3'`

`gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.3'`

*Install development dependencies*

1) `bundle update i18n` (i'm thinking this is optional but not sure)

2) `bundle install`

Install install generators to set up Spree:

1) `rails g spree:install --user_class=Spree::User`

You will be asked to setup an admin account
`Email [spree@example.com]: admin@cucg.com`
`Password [spree123]:`

then just run `rails s` and you will be all set

I just followed this [Spree Official Installation Guide](https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/getting_started_tutorial.html) and everything worked jut fine

Comment: Can you please guide me how did you resolve this error? Hope you are still active on stackoverflow

Comment: [Sathwik Gangisetty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7102610/sathwik-gangisetty) i have updated the answer instructions on how i have created my project so maybe that way you could make it work? let me know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

You need to include html to your haml file name.

Like so:

```
your_file_name.html.haml
```

Rename your index file to:

```
index.html.haml
```

Read more about haml here:

http://haml.info/tutorial.html